# JavaScript email validation using getElementById method

Tags: javascript, email-validation, getelementbyid

for email validation I have these two input fields:

```
<input class="inputbox" type="text" name="data[subscriber][email]" id="field_email" size="40" value="'.$this->escape(@$this->subscriber->email).'"/>

<input class="inputbox" type="text" name="data[subscriber][retype_email]" id="field_retype_email" size="40" value="" onblur="confirm_email()" />
```

the name of the input fields was different ( input1_name, input2_name ), and I had working script:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function confirm_email() {
email = document.adminForm.input1_name.value;
re_email = document.adminForm.input2_name.value;
if ( email != re_email ) {
alert ("ERROR: El correo electronico no coincide. Escribe tu correo electronico nuevamente")
document.adminForm.input1_name.value = "";
document.adminForm.input2_name.value = "";
document.adminForm.input1_name.focus();
}
else {}
}
</script>
```

BUT I NEED to access the element by id, because the input element needs to be formatted with brackets (this does not work in javascript). And so I derived the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_email(){
    var email = document.getElementById('field_email');
    var re_email = document.getElementById('field_retype_email');
    if( email != re_email )
        alert("ERROR: El correo electronico no coincide. Escribe tu correo electronico nuevamente")
        document.getElementById('field_email').value = "";
        document.getElementById('field_retype_email') = "";
        document.getElementById('field_email').focus();
    else {} 
}
</script>
```

IT DOESN'T WORK

If I only use this part of the script it works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function confirm_email(){
        var email = document.getElementById('field_email');
        var re_email = document.getElementById('field_retype_email');
        if( email != re_email )
            alert("ERROR: El correo electronico no coincide. Escribe tu correo electronico nuevamente")
            else {} 
    }
    </script>
```

which means that these lines are wrong:

```
        document.getElementById('field_email').value = "";
        document.getElementById('field_retype_email') = "";
        document.getElementById('field_email').focus();
```

but, I want the input elements to reset, and the first input element to be on focus (get the effect that I got when I used the first snippet of code that worked).

How can I do this with the getElementById method?

Thanx

Comment: Related: `if( email != re_email )` is comparing the *elements*, which will always be different, you want `if( email.value != re_email.value )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some braces, and some `.value`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_email(){
    var email = document.getElementById('field_email').value;
    var re_email = document.getElementById('field_retype_email').value;
    if( email != re_email ) {    //  <-- here
        alert("ERROR: El correo electronico no coincide. Escribe tu correo electronico nuevamente")
        document.getElementById('field_email').value = "";
        document.getElementById('field_retype_email').value = "";
        document.getElementById('field_email').focus();
    }    // <-- and here
    else {} 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some `.value` attributes in your script.  Does this work for you?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirm_email(){
    var email = document.getElementById('field_email').value;
    var re_email = document.getElementById('field_retype_email').value;
    if( email != re_email ) {
        alert("ERROR: El correo electronico no coincide. Escribe tu correo electronico nuevamente")
        document.getElementById('field_email').value = "";
        document.getElementById('field_retype_email').value = "";
        document.getElementById('field_email').focus();
    }
    else {} 
}
</script>
```

Comment: NOTE: I added some curly braces too per Andrew's answer :)